# How to get text on an ActionBar Icon?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I want something like this:

[image]

The 3rd icon is for notifications and it is just a png image now. Is it possible to do something, so that i can change the text/number ie.., 03 programatically to show the actual no.of notifications.

Thank You

Comment: Looks like it is an image but will wait for confirmed answer

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Here is some example code that worked for me.

1: Create a layout for your badge menu item.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right" >

    <!-- Menu Item Image -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bkg_actionbar_notify_off" />

    <!-- Badge Count -->    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_notifcation_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:text="99"
        android:textColor="@color/holo_orange_dark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

2: Create a menu item in res/menu and set the actionLayout to your layout

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/badge"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_badge_layout"
        android:icon="@drawable/icn_menu_posts"
        android:showAsAction="always">
    </item>
</menu>
```

3: Then in onCreateOptionsMenu of your activity or fragment you can do something like this...

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.badge, menu);

    RelativeLayout badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.badge).getActionView();
    TextView tv = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textview);
    tv.setText("12");
}
```

Note: If you wanted to change the badge count later on, you could store a reference to the Menu object passed to onCreateOptionsMenu and use the same code to get the required view and set a value.

=== ApCompat Warning ==================================================

If using the AppCompatActivity then you must set the actionView in `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
      MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.badge);
      MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.actionbar_badge_layout);
      RelativeLayout notifCount = (RelativeLayout) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

    TextView tv = (TextView) notifCount.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textview);
    tv.setText("12");

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

Comment: Thanks your is working good but the problem is notification_menu becomes unclickable.... where I might be wrong?

Comment: You can override onCreateOptions in an activity which passes you the a Menu object, then call menu.getItem(i).getActionView().setOnClickListener where i is the index of your visible menu item, then then in your OnClickListener check that v.getId() == R.id.badge (this is the id of your menu item not any of the views)...

Comment: working fine..Still unable to get the onclick working on the menu item click. Could you post that code as well?

Comment: I got onclick working by changing ImageView in actionbar_badge_layout with ImageButton with id imagebuttonid and then adding onClick listener to that button: MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.actionbar_badge_layout)).findViewById(R.id.imagebuttonid).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    System.out.println("clicked");   
   }
});

Comment: Hey I used your technique and it worked but I also want multiple action icons but one 1 with badge.. the problem here is that the other icons are not being shown..

Comment: I'm getting a null pointer at `RelativeLayout badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.action_choose_programs).getActionView();`, any thoughts?

Comment: Is action_choose_programs the id of your menu > item or the id of the actionView layout?

Comment: In the below line I am getting null pointer exception. TextView tv = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textview);... I think the badgeLayout is null...Any idea?

Comment: Have you set a layout that contains a textview with the id actionbar_notifcation_textview to be the actionLayout of the menu item in question?

Comment: I copied exactly same code but `TextView tv = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textview);` here I am getting nullpointer error do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you have a menu item xml file in res/menu that has an <item> with an id of badge? If not you will get a null pointer trying to access badgeLayout. If that does exist then you need to make sure you have a layout xml file with a textview that has an id of actionbar_notifcation_textview

Comment: Those getting a null pointer just make sure that when using `setText` on the textview, you are using a string.

Comment: Thanks so much for the great answer! Just to add, for AppCompat, instead of using code to `setActionView`, you can just use the `app:` namespace to make it work in xml, something like: `app:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_badge_layout"`

Comment: You have to redirect the click event:

    // Manually handle the click
item.getActionView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
});

Comment: Thanks, a good solution. If you want to realize onClickListener, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39174874/2914140.

Answer (score 8):

One option is to create your own action view for this. Use `android:actionLayout` in the XML and `getActionView()` in Java after inflation to manipulate it. Your action view would be an `ImageView` (for the icon) and... something for the badge. I suspect that you will find that trying to make that badge via text will be difficult, and that you are better served with a bunch of badge images, one of which you layer on top of the icon (e.g., via `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`, or by wrapping the icon in a `LayerListDrawable`).

Another option is simply to have N versions of the icon+badge, perhaps wrapped in a `LevelListDrawable`, that you choose from at runtime.

Comment: But **actionLayout** i what i see once i click on the MenuItem. How to have it as a initial Icon? Right now the default it give a Text **NOTIFICATIONS**

Comment: @Archie.bpgc: "But actionLayout i what i see once i click on the MenuItem" -- no, the `actionLayout` is used immediately, instead of an "initial icon".

Comment: But it shows title of the MenuItem initially and when clicked then only it gives the **actionLayout** i set :(

Comment: @Archie.bpgc: Not if you do it right. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/ActionBarDemo

Comment: In the code you provided. Why are both **icon** and **actionLayout** set to the add menu item. Isn't the **actionLayout** supposed to be the **icon**?

Comment: @Archie.bpgc: The icon probably is not needed.

Comment: @CommonsWare Im using support lib 7 for the ActionBar. Whats an alternative for .getActionView(); for such case

Comment: Can we set animation when we call setNotificationCount nmethod to add count ?

Comment: @Rstar: Not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Had to make some changes to domji84's answers. For some reason the clicking on imageview was not calling the click event, it works find after removing the clicklabe = "true" from image view.

menu_item_cart.xml

```
    <!-- Menu Item Image -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <!-- Badge Count -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cartCountTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="99"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_cart"
        android:title="test"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_cart_count"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Activity code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart).getActionView().setOnClickListener(this);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart) returns null app crashes here.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use Custom action bar with default action bar...
firstly prepare layout by xml or java.then use display matrics and get window manager.After this inflate the layout. like this

```
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    View mactionbar = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main2, null);
```