# OnOptionsItemSelected not invoked though implemented mehtods with ScrollView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, fragment, android-scrollview

onOptionsItemSelected is not invoked both in the Activity and the Fragment, even though I implemented the methods as described here: [Add onOptionsItemSelected calling in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316800/add-onoptionsitemselected-calling-in-fragment)
I have an activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); // false by default. so goes to fragment
    // If return true, than stay in the activity
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onOptionsItemSelected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            // false by default. so goes to fragment
            // If returns true stays in activity.
    }
}
```

and this is the fragment that doesn't work:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);((AppCompatActivity)activity).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}



@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_edit_mode,menu);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(activity,"onOptionItemSelected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // Not Invoked!!!
    if (!isDataInitialized()) return true;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

          case R.id.item_share:  // Share Icon
            callUsernamesDialog();
            return true;


        case android.R.id.home: // Back pressing
            ( (ActivityProfile)activity).onBackPressed();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

It's onOptionsItemSelected is not called but the menu is inflated successfully.
In other fragments everything works fine and I don't see any difference in the implementation.
In the other fragments onOptionsItemSelected is invoked both in the activity and the fragment. What can I look for in this particular fragment that can prevent it from working ?

A help would be appreciated!!! Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
**I found the solution and now the items clicks are available but I have a question on that.**

The problem was that I used a scrollView in the fragment because I have many elements in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_edit_data_layout"
    tools:context=".UserStuff.EditData.FragmentEditData"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
        android:text="@string/edit_data"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_title"
        style="@android:style/Widget.AutoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:hint="@string/title"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="@string/folder_category"
            />
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standard_21"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/btn_category"
            android:text="@string/untitled"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            />
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="@string/refresh"
            android:id="@+id/btn_refresh"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_description"
        style="@android:style/Widget.AutoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:hint="@string/description"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_edit_data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="@string/tap_to_edit"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_edit_data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Removing the ScrollView and using the LinearLayout as the root view solved the problem, the question is Why ? I can't see docs on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this it is working myside
to add menu in activity

```
 @Override  
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.  
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_edit_mode, menu);  
    return true;  
}  

@Override  
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
   int id = item.getItemId();  
    switch (id){  
        case R.id.item1:  
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item 1 Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            return true;  
        case R.id.item2:  
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item 2 Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            return true;  
        case R.id.item3:  
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item 3 Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            return true;  
        default:  
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);  
    }  
}
```

for setting menu in fragment

Add setHasOptionsMenu(true) method in your Fragment's onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method.

Override onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) (if you want to do something different in your Fragment's menu) and onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) methods in your Fragment.

Inside your onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) Activity's method, make sure you return false when the menu item action would be implemented in onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) Fragment's method.

Activity

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.activity_menu_item:

            // Do Activity menu item stuff here
            return true;

        case R.id.fragment_menu_item:

            // Not implemented here
            return false;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Fragment

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Do something that differs the Activity's menu here
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.activity_menu_item:
            // Not implemented here
            return false;
        case R.id.fragment_menu_item:
            // Do Fragment menu item stuff here
            return true;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I have different menus for every fragment in the activity, so returning true in Activity's onCreateOptionsMenu will prevent from inflating the other menus in fragments of the activity. Am I missing something

Comment: Thanks for your replies and updates.. I found the problem wasn't in the code but in the layout of the fragment so I updated the question.