# Android: Custom option menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view, android-optionsmenu

I am developing an application in which i want to show a one custom menu item which shows count and rest menu items are default type of item as shown in image below.

[image]

My code of menu.xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_1"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_1"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:title="@string/option_1"
        myapp:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_2"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_2"
        android:orderInCategory="102"
        android:title="@string/option_2"
        myapp:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_3"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_3"
        android:orderInCategory="103"
        android:title="@string/option_3"
        myapp:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_4"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_4"
        android:orderInCategory="104"
        android:title="@string/option_4"
        myapp:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_5"
        android:orderInCategory="105"
        android:title="@string/option_5"
        myapp:showAsAction="never"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_badge_layout" />
</menu>
```

My code of actionbar_badge_layout.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_badge_layout" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_notifcation_textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/option_1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/actionbar_notifcation_count_textview"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_notifcation_count_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="99"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_circle" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my fragment what i done is :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myfragment, container,false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ((SlidingBaseActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("My Fragment");
    ((SlidingBaseActivity) getActivity()).keepMenuClosed(false);
    ((SlidingBaseActivity) getActivity()).makeActionOverflowMenuShown();
    initView(view);
    dialog = Helper.showPleaseWaitDialog(getActivity());
    getdata();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) { 
    menu.findItem(R.id.option_1).setVisible(true);
    menu.findItem(R.id.option_1).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    menu.findItem(R.id.option_2).setVisible(true);
    menu.findItem(R.id.option_2).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    menu.findItem(R.id.option_3).setVisible(true);
    menu.findItem(R.id.option_3).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    menu.findItem(R.id.option_4).setVisible(true);
    menu.findItem(R.id.option_4).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    menu.findItem(R.id.option_5).setVisible(true);
    menu.findItem(R.id.option_5).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

    RelativeLayout badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.option_5).getActionView();
    TextView textViewMenuText = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textview);
    textViewMenuText.setText("Notification ");
    TextView textViewCount = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_count_textview);
    textViewCount.setText("99");

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

But i am getting **null pointer exception** when i navigate to the respective fragment. 
I follow the max voted answer from the [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288989/how-to-get-text-on-an-actionbar-icon/16648170#16648170)

What i am missing or doing wrong? Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

In your onCreateOptionsMenu you are trying this:

```
RelativeLayout badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.option_5).getActionView();
```

The '`id`' to the item is wrong here. You have set the id as '`menu_5`' and trying to fetch with '`option_5`'. Which I see is exactly your '`title`' to the menu item.