# attempting to display icon with text android ActionBar

Tags: android, xml

I am attempting to display icon with search bar in Android nav bar but it just keeps displaying just the icon. Here is my xml code

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_login"
        android:title="Login"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
```

here the xml full code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


   <item android:id="@+id/action_login"
        android:title="Login"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
</menu>
```

what could be wrong

Comment: In my machine, your code is working! Share your full menu xml file

Comment: Done...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code worked properly in Android 5.0 and above.

But in android 4.2 display only icon, not text!!

So if you worked on below 5.0 then use `actionLayout`.

Refer this answer: 
[How to get text on an ActionBar Icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288989/how-to-get-text-on-an-actionbar-icon)

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem by following code:

1- Create menu in menu folder

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
   android:id="@+id/action_sign"
   android:title="Sing In"
   app:showAsAction="always|withText"
   app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_sign" />
```

2- app:actionLayout is the key word, Then create layout named menu_sign and put textView in it. the icon will displayed by drawableLeft

```
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_user_sign"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:text="@string/text"
     android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_5"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_10"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_10"
     android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

3- Add listener for your menu

```
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_sign, menu);
signItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_sign);
signItem.getActionView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onOptionsItemSelected(signItem);
    }
});
```

Comment: where is this value initialized >>> signItem

Comment: final MenuItem signItem= menu.findItem(R.id.action_sign);

Answer (score -1):

Change this -:

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock"
```

To-:

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_lock_lock"
```

or

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_lock_lock"
```

Comment: Float has issue with text image is displaying